# let variable null when passing from parent to child | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have a variable that I don't want to bind to state in React. So I declared it as `let` with initial value as null. Later with event I set its value in parent and then pass it to child. But in child its value is getting null. Not sure what mistake I am making. Below is the code.

```
function Parent() {

    const[showChild, setShowChild] = useState(false);
    let data = null;

    const setData = () => {
      data = 'Test';
      setShowChild(true);
      console.log('function called');
    };

    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={setData}>
          Click Me
        </button>
        {showChild && <Child data={data} />}
      </>
    );
}

function Child({data}) {
    console.log('data '  + data);
    return (
      <>
        <h2>
          {data}
        </h2>
      </>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />, 
  document.getElementById('mountNode'),
);
```

Comment: `data` is _re-declared_ and initialized with `null` every time your component re-renders.

Comment: @Yousaf Is there any way apart binding it to state I can declare it as local variable?

Comment: You could use `useRef` hook. What's the problem with setting it in state?

Comment: I dont want to do rendering whenever state of data changes

Comment: You are updating `showChild` when `data` changes. You could remove that and put `data` in the state.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist state you have to use `useState` as you did in the first line. so instead of manually `let data ...` and `const setData` you should have something like the following:

`const [data, setData] = useState(null)`

Comment: I don't want to bind to state as I don't to do rendering whenever state of data changes.

Comment: @rns You will need to use state, the child function has to re render when `data` changes from null to `Test`.

Answer (score 0):

You sould use `useState`, whenever the state changes in parent, child will be render again.

I changed your example a little bit to show you what happen exactly, child just shows the value that parent has sent.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Parent=()=> {
 const[showChild, setShowChild] = useState(false);
 const[data, setData] = useState(0);
    //let data = null;

    const handleClick = () => {
      setData((prev=>prev+1));
      setShowChild(true);
      console.log('function called');
    };
    return (
      <div>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>
          Click Me
        </button>
        {showChild && <Child data={data} />}
      </div>
    );
}
const Child=({data})=> {
    console.log('data '  + data);
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>
          {data}
        </h2>
      </div>
    );
}


ReactDOM.render( <Parent/> ,
  document.getElementById("mountNode")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="mountNode"></div>
```